# jQuery selector excluding other elements in events

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, addeventlistener, jquery-events

I have a form that I want to prevent submit it when user press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
But there are 3 inputs that I want to exclude of this "rule".

Doing this I can prevent the submit event when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed:

```
  $(document).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  });
```

But how can I exclude my three inputs from this rules?

Here is what I tried out:

```
  $(document).not("#input1", "#input2", "#input3").keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  });
```

And this other:

```
  $(document).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
      if ($(event.target).is('#input1') == false || $(event.target).is('#input2') == false || $(event.target).is('#input3') == false) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
```

My really intention is prevent enter on ALL inputs excluding that three inputs, but when Enter is pressed in one of that inputs I like to run a `trigger()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test whether the target *is* one of the elements you want to exclude. If this is true, return from the handler immediately. You also need to call `event.stopPropagation()`, otherwise the event will bubble out to other elements that aren't the excluded elements.

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        if ($(event.target).is("#input1,#input2,#input3")) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            return;
        }
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Cool, but there is a way to abstract it a bit more? I want to call a trigger. If Enter is pressed on `$("#input1")` then `$(".input1").trigger("click")` I think with `event.target` and concatenate in the `trigger` method but I can't get it work :(

Comment: You could add `$(event.target).trigger("click")`

Comment: Something is not working :/ with all inputs the event is prevented, but if I press Enter on one of the three inputs, the form fire the submission.

Comment: By the way, `$(event.target).trigger("click")` will not select something like `$(".input3")` please note the `class selector`.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the difference, thought you wanted to click on the target. `$('.' + event.target.id).trigger("click")`

Comment: Sorry, @Barmar, but I think something is not working, could you please take a look at this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/j1yh8kne/1/ ?

Comment: What isn't working? The trigger won't do anything because there's nothing with that class in your HTML.

Comment: That's true, but that's not the problem. If I press the enter key on `#input1` or `#input2` or `#input3`, the form is submitted, the behaviour is the opposite.

Comment: The question says that form submit should be prevented if you press enter anywhere except `#input1`, `#input2`, or `#input3`. That's what happens.

Comment: I have misexplained, sorry.